# jQuery Array is not finding objects in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following area:

myArray which console outputs as:

```
[>Object, >Object, >Object, >Object]
```

The last item opened:

```
Object
helper: true
id: 0
__proto__: Object
```

I would like to find and then remove this item from my array but getting stuck here with always -1. ideas?

```
jQuery.inArray([{'helper':true}], myArray)
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll note that `({key:"value"} == {key:"value"})` evaluates to `false` which should show you why your approach wont work.

Comment: +1 @Griffin: It's important to remember that JavaScript does have the concept of object references.  People can forget that's how garbage collection works!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of `jQuery.inArray` to find the unwanted object and remove it from the array:

```
var arr = [
 { helper: false },
 { helper: true },
 { helper: false }
];

var found = -1;
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, obj) {
 if (obj.helper) {
  found = index;
  return false;
 }
});

if (found > -1) {
 arr.splice(found, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out elements of an `Array` with [`jQuery.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
myArray = $.grep(myArray, function (item) {
    return !item.helper;
});
```

---

As for `inArray`: Your 1st argument is defining a new `Array` and `Object`. As they're `new` here, they can't also be within `myArray`.